# Does "wobble" sound negative?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, word-usage

I'm launching a project which I want to make big as possible. I want to find a name, but I'm not looking for any real meanings. This project is a web tool *(Javascript prototype & API)* so I want to give it an English name. The tool will have a lot of "~" key, so I'm trying to find a word that matches the representation of this symbole. This is how I came up with **"Wobble"**, however it's maybe too metaphoric because "Wobble" doesn't really mean "wave" right?

Is wobble a negative word? Which word could match the tilde and which sounds positive beside "wave"?

Thanks!

Comment: Is a table [wobbles](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wobble), it is unstable. If I drink too much alcohol I may wobble on my feet and fall over. A voice wobbles when the person is near to tears. Yep, *wobble* is not exactly a positive term.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with "Wobble" as a product name.  It's got an amusing sound to it and would provoke a smile in most people.

Comment: FWIW, one of my physics professors called it a "twiddle"; that sounds like a reasonable name to me.

Comment: Just a heads up, in the US right now, this is what [Wobble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qd6UI6wEIsU) means, especially to the younger generation.  (Although hopefully only briefly :P )

Comment: @Mari-LouA Jello wobbles & that's not negative.

Comment: Weebles wobble (but they don't fall down).

Comment: That really all depends, how is the symbol being used in the context of the applicaiton?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam and my son used to love saying "wibbly-wobbly" for my bouncy bits :) (when he was a small child, I hasten to add!)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that almost qualifies as TMI, but I can't help smiling about it!  In fact, I'm grinning from ear to ear.  LMAO. I'm going to tell my new wife all about you -- she's got a quirky sense of humour, too.

Comment: I wobbly wobbly - One Big Union.

Comment: "The tool will have a lot of [Tilda] key"? Please rephrase. (squigglies?) Thankfully the Earth wobbles or we'd have no seasons. Also that it doesn't wobble too much (thanks to the moon), if it did we'd all be dead. So... um.

Answer (score 23):

This may be somewhat opinion based, but I don't think that *wobble* is negative-sounding in and of itself. I think it is fun and silly, in a good way - and it seems to strike the right tone for a web tool, as these often do have silly names (such as '[Pyjamas](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Pyjamas)' or '[Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/)').

Positive meanings of *wobble* are found in the wobbling of a jelly, or a musical wobble board - and musician [Jah Wobble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jah_Wobble) chose it as a name that "people would never forget".

I would think that calling a software tool 'wobble' would only be negative if the tool starts to get a reputation for being unreliable - but of course you are going to make sure that doesn't happen, aren't you?

Comment: Also, "wibbly wobbly timey wimey".

Answer (score 5):

I think you should go with something more neutral. It is clear from the other responses that "Wobble" can be seen as positive or negative. So I think you should try moving towards something like:

**Squiggle**

> noun
>   noun: squiggle; plural noun: squiggles
>   1.
>   a short line that curls and loops in an irregular way.
>   "some prescriptions are a series of meaningless squiggles"

synonyms:   wavy line, doodle

Answer (score 5):

To me 'wobble' does have a bit of a negative connotation, as a wobble is typically something to be avoided, although in some cases, it could also be somewhat endearing.  It's a bit like 'toddle' in that respect.

On a side note, given the [actual name of the `~` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde),  I'm going to go the less literal and slightly *punnier* route, and suggest the actual name "Matilda".

Comment: I like Matilda, I'd add a suggestion for Matilde, or maTilde if you want to play with formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the type of product Wobble can have a meaning of either funny or unsturdy/off balance.

If you have a table or a chair that wobbles, people see that negatively.

If you have a ball or other toy that wobbles, it makes it more fun.

Since you are making a tool, wobble might not be appropriate to use as a product name in this case.

Two good words I can think of that might correspond to the ~ symbol would be ripple or corkscrew. Either one puts forth a more positive image.

Comment: I like 'ripple', but sadly it's already 'taken' in the software world - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_(payment_protocol).

Comment: And there's also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corkscrew_(program)

Comment: @topomorto -- Thankfully that one's already taken -- it would be terrible for a web site.

Comment: A quick Google shows that Wobble is the name of a piece of software too. (It's not on Wikipedia, and I'm not going to link to a vendor, so you'll have to Google yourself.)

Comment: @MrLister do you mean Wobble 2.3 Dubstep Grime Generator?

Answer (score 2):

To help provide a modern contextual background in support of the name Wobble, I want to highlight that the word wobble has actually received a significant positive connotation in certain cultural subsets. Most famously in the past decade (and underground for a decade and change before that) a genre of music has been evolving that actually centers around something called a "bass wobble".

You may have heard of Dubstep, and may or may not find it annoying or intolerable, but that is neither here nor there. The point is that a large section of the population has a very positive emotional affect to the word wobble and to them it typically elicits good feelings, happiness, and perhaps even euphoria. On that grounds, I believe that the word wobble is about as good a choice for a development tool as windows or apple is for an operating system.

After all, though a table can wobble, a person can be defenestrated, and Eve or the wicked stepmother can ruin your life with an apple, so who's to say which is positive and which is negative?

Answer (score 1):

The character on the key is the [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) character, and is part of a Spanish character, ñ. In Spanish, the ñ character is pronounced just like an "n" followed by a consonant "y" as in "señor" (mister/sir) or "mañana" (tomorrow).

Though if you're afraid your audience might not know that the word "tilde" refers to that symbol, I might suggest:

[Squiggle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/squiggle)

> noun
>
> 1. a short, irregular curve or twist, as in writing or drawing.

It's informal but it's a better match than wobble, which is generally thought of as a verb or motion, while squiggle is generally thought of as a noun that refers to a curvy, twisty line--a pretty decent description of the tilde character.

Comment: Some people also refer to this symbol as a "twiddle".

Answer (score 0):

Ripple might be a good subsitute.

Another interesting way to describe it could be "Sine" as the tilde closely approximates a Sine wave